# Opentelemetry Kubeletstats receiver - Unable to get network stats in Openshift 4

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector, k8s-rolebinding

I need help on kubeletstats receiver.
I'm using the below configuration in opentelemetry collector which is running in openshift.

```
...
image: 'ghcr.io/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-releases/opentelemetry-collector-contrib:0.94.0'
spec:
  config: |
    receivers:
      kubeletstats/node:
          collection_interval: 5s
          initial_delay: 1s
          auth_type: "serviceAccount"
          endpoint: "https://${K8S_NODE_NAME}:10250"
          insecure_skip_verify: true
          metrics:
            k8s.node.cpu.usage:
               enabled: true
            k8s.node.cpu.utilization:
               enabled: false
          metric_groups:
            - node
```

And the ClusterRole provided is

```
...
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - '*'
  resources:
  - '*'
  verbs:
  - '*'
- nonResourceURLs:
  - '*'
  verbs:
  - '*'
```

I can able to get the below metrics

- **k8s.node.cpu.time**
- **k8s.node.filesystem.available**
- **k8s.node.filesystem.capacity**
- **k8s.node.filesystem.usage**
- **k8s.node.memory.available**
- **k8s.node.memory.major_page_faults**
- **k8s.node.memory.page_faults**
- **k8s.node.memory.rss**
- **k8s.node.memory.usage**
- **k8s.node.memory.working_set**
- **k8s.node.cpu.usage**

But there is no metrics for network

- **k8s.node.network.errors**
- **k8s.node.network.io**

What possibly could be the reason. Am I missing something in ClusterRole configuration ?
Thanks in Advance !!